# Why does Stack Overflow limits the number links per message to 2?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, new-users

I like SO/SE, since I often find very good answers that are nowhere else. So, from time to time, when I encounter unanswered questions, I take the time to log-in and write a correct answer, in order to take my turn in helping those that do not know things that I know.

Today, I discovered that I cannot post more than 2 links in my answer, because my reputation is 0 (yes, I do not have time to help so often and people probably don't take the time to +1 my answers). However, the person was asking for some tools that can help solve his task and I had 3 tools to propose with 4 links to describe them. That's not what I call spamming... And that was the way to respond correctly to the question.

I don't have so much time to waste in logging-in and writing a correct answer... I overcome my dislikes and do so because I like to retaliate and help others when they help me. I'm sorry to say that, but if this limit stays, I'm off.

So my questions are: why this limit? Why so low?

Comment: "the person was asking for some tools that can help solve his task" - that's an off-topic question then.

Comment: Because of Spammers. You need to "prove" that you're not a spammer by earning (a very small amount of) reputation.

Comment: @JoachimSauer While I agree that this is the reason, in my experience with dealing with spammers they almost always only post one single link in their posts. [GET CHEAP JORDANS HERE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188957/why-does-stackoverflow-limits-the-number-links-per-message-to-2) sort of thing.

Comment: @JonW: That's because they are limited. Anywhere *else* they post 100 links.